# Photos do not show on SEO platform built into a wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, php

I’m building an SEO application.

I built a plugin from the folder with the application. So, the folder is called `body_call` and inside has the `body.php`, the `index.php` (in which I placed the plugin “header copyright”) and other functions like forms and so on. In this folder (`body_call`) I also have the image folder that has the images, the css folder that has the `style.css` and the js folder.

So, I made the function to be called from the new plugin `platform ()` and I called it from a template that I made called keywords (since the platform is about SEO keywords).

The images do not show! And the `style.css` is not accessible, but the content from the body is more or less there (its scramble). I used the path for the images like this: `images/image.jpg` and the style sheet is called the same way: `css/style.css`. All this inside the `body_call` folder (parent folder / plugin folder).

Another problem is the plugin shows on `localhost/keywords` but when I click on a link it goes to `localhost/keywords/index.php` and gives a page not found

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it seem like you are using relative URLs-- "I used the path for the images like this: images/image.jpg ..."

Don't use relative URLs in WordPress. Relative paths are not reliable, except in stylesheets. They do work in stylesheets.

Use functions like [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) and [these other related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories).